# Emergency boot - Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 21.04 running on my RPi v4 4GB had some problems with the USB HDDs disappearing and locked up when I tried to access them, so I had to pull the plug.

Now when I try to boot (without the USB HDDs connected), it boots to emergency mode, with no network access (which is a pain as I was administering it remotely via Putty) and if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to continue it says:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for multi-user.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in the transaction.
```

I was running it without a GUI, just using the console and I thought I'd set it not to boot to the GUI but it shows the Ubuntu splash screen before booting to emergency mode.

Is there an easy way to fix this, bearing in mind that without any remote access I can't really dig through the logs and copy any messages to paste here, or will it be easier to just reflash the SD card and start again?